# Merge two arrays, avoiding duplicates using immutable pattern in redux

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, lodash

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
let A = [a,b,c,d]
let B = [c,d,e]
```

where each of the letters is an object that has several properties, one of which is an `id` which is unique in my domain. The merged result would then be

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
```

where `[c,d]` originate from B.

Using an elegant approach, how would I merge these two arrays in a way that any element in `B` would overwrite any existing one in `A` and all others remain untouched. So it's a union with `B` elements taking precedence in case of a conflict.

I have two ideas (using ES6 and lodash):

```
//remove same elements first, then join arrays
let ids = new Set(B.map(e => e.id));
let newState = _.reject(A, constraint => ids.has(constraint.id));
return newState.concat(B);

//convert both to hashmap, join, then take values
let B_map = _.keyBy(B, 'id');
let A_map = _.keyBy(A, 'id');
return {...A_map, ...B_map}.values();
```

Is there a shorter / more concise / more readable version? Maybe one without external dependencies? I'm essentially looking for something like

[image]

Where equality between any element is defined by the `id` property (or a comparator function in v2).

Comment: the wanted result is `[a, b]` ... or?

Comment: or are you asking for the result to be `[a,b,c,d]` where `c,d` are from `B`?

Comment: I improved the question a bit to clarify the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without external dependencies, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to extract elements from `A` that don't have ids in `B` and `concat` that with `B`:

```js
const A = [{id: 1, name: 'x'}, {id: 2, name: 'y'}, {id: 3, name: 'z'}];
const B = [{id: 2, name: 'hello'}];

let ids = new Set(B.map(e => e.id));
let newState = A.filter(a => !ids.has(a.id)).concat(B);

console.log(newState);
```

Comment: I chose this answer as it is using only 2 instead of 1 line with vanilla javascript. However, Ibrahims is the most appropriate when considering that I use lodash. Thanks!

Comment: I posted another solution that follows the more redux styled approach.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using lodash, you can use `_.unionBy` which merges the arrays using a criterion by which uniqueness is computed:

```
let result = _.unionBy(B, A, "id");
```

Start with `B` before `A`, so that in case of duplicates, `B` values are taken instead of `A` ones.

**Example:**

```js
let A = [
  { id: "a", arr: "A" },
  { id: "b", arr: "A" },
  { id: "c", arr: "A" },
  { id: "d", arr: "A" }
];

let B = [
  { id: "b", arr: "B" },
  { id: "d", arr: "B" }
];

let result = _.unionBy(B, A, "id");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** This messes up the order of the items, the duplicates come first, then the rest.

Comment: This one-liner is actually what I discovered today, a day later. I guess there are going to be two right answers. This one and the one by @slider who offers a vanilla solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash's `_.differenceBy(A, B)` to remove all items that exist in `B` from `A`, and then combine with `B` items. This will preserve the order of A items before B items.

```js
const A = [{"id":"a","arr":"A"},{"id":"b","arr":"A"},{"id":"c","arr":"A"},{"id":"d","arr":"A"}];

const B = [{"id":"c","arr":"B"},{"id":"d","arr":"B"}];

const result = [..._.differenceBy(A, B, 'id'), ...B];

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good, but the `unionBy` seems to be a tad more intuitive, as it creates a union with duplicates removed by an iteratee.

Comment: The order of the Union is the problem - B before A.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that follows more of the redux styled approach...

```
// imported redux actions (these are simply strings)
import {
    SOME_DEFINED_ACTION_CASE
} from '../actions/someActions';

const initialState = {
    reduxList: []
}

// reducer function
export default function someReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOME_DEFINED_ACTION_CASE: {
            let ids = new Set(action.payload.map(e => e.id));
            let newState = state.reduxList.filter(a => !ids.has(a.id)).concat(action.payload);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                reduxList: newState
            });
        }
    }
}
```